# HTML5 canvas make holes in images

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do several animated objects in HTML5 canvas. And I need to make hole in some images when they cross with another ones. And i need fixed delay between cadrs.
So I done this: [youtube-example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqZS__fC9kM)
But it work rather slow
My way:
As you can see on video- Units should be visible in any case and I making holes in other objects for this.
I get  images  from server and check if units cross other objects in each cadr.
Than if units cross them, I making hole in  other objects

Code:
 Holc- where need hole.
ObjUnit- unit who make hole.

```
{
    Holc.wait = true;
    var difY = ObjUnit.PosY - Holc.PosY;
    var difX = ObjUnit.PosX - Holc.PosX;
    var tempc = 0;
    tmpcontext.beginPath();
    tmpcontext.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    var gradient = tmpcontext.createRadialGradient(maxUnitX + difX + ObjUnit.height / 2, maxUnitY + difY + ObjUnit.height / 2, 0,
    maxUnitX + difX + ObjUnit.height / 2, maxUnitY + difY + ObjUnit.height / 2, ObjUnit.height / 2 + 10);
    gradient.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)');
    tmpcontext.fillStyle = gradient;
    tmpcontext.fillRect(maxUnitX + difX, maxUnitY + difY, ObjUnit.width, ObjUnit.height);

}
```

I do this code for each Unit who cross object. And after this i doing this:

```
if (Holc.wait == true) {
    MainTimerInterval.AllLoaded = false;
    var imageData = tmpcontext.getImageData(maxUnitX, maxUnitY, Holc.width, Holc.height);
    var tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var tmpcontext = tmpCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tmpCanvas.width = Holc.width;
    tmpCanvas.height = Holc.height;
    tmpcontext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    varmass.needtoload++;
    PictureData.push({
        TextureId: finmass[i][j2].TextureId,
        Version: "No",
        SizeofKadr: PictureData[j3].SizeofKadr,
        isNeedHole: PictureData[j3].isNeedHole,
        Image: new Image()
    });
    PictureData[PictureData.length - 1].Image.onload = function () {
        varmass.loaded++;
    }
    PictureData[PictureData.length - 1].Image.src = tmpCanvas.toDataURL();
}
```

As you see i cut  Radial Gradient from source image on temporary canvas and create Image  from  temporary canvas data and then push it to images array.

And when `varmass.needtoload==varmass.loaded` I begin drawing animation.
And it works very slow.
**I think  slow operation is this:**

```
PictureData[PictureData.length - 1].Image.src = tmpCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Have you any idea how to do this more effective?